# Can't connect to AWS EC2 public ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I can SSH ok to my AWS EC2 instance. Grizzly has been installed and started.

```
 tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8080       :::*                        LISTEN
```

I can't connect through a browser from my local machine to the EC2 public IP http://public ip:8080/index. I had a security group with incoming access to HTTP port 8080 allowed and all outgoing allowed. I also tried allowing ICMP for a ping but I can't ping it either. I removed all security group constraints and that didn't work either. I checked iptables and there are no rules to restrict anything.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this URL correct http ://public ip:8080/index or you want to use  http ://public ip:8080/index.html or php

Comment: it was http://54.210.117.202:8080/index or http://54.210.117.202:8080/index.jsp since its a jsp. I rebooted the instance now to see if that would fix it so that changed the ip. I couldn't telnet to port 80 or ping either.

Comment: Are you sure 8080 is open in the security group? I tried telnet 54.210.117.202 8080 and it is timing out for me

Comment: I tried stopping iptables service etc from http://serverfault.com/questions/464292/can-not-access-ec2-server-via-ip-address but I still can't telnet ip 80

Comment: That the old ip. It was open in the security group but now I removed all rules so everything is allowed as I understand it.

Comment: I don't think its wise to put it on a public web site.

Comment: Ok then solution is there is some application issue if you say the port is open in security group. If port 80 is open in security group telnet command runs seamlessly you can check this example for my EC2 instance that has port 80 open to world telnet 54.235.105.61 80 same goes for port 8080

Comment: telnet doesn't connect so it's not an application issue: telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: By application issue I mean to say server side issue.

Comment: Well after rebooting the instance and thus getting a new ip. I can't telnet to the new ip on port 80. So grrizzy and the jsp are not the issue. Just AWS, network, and the OS of the instance.

Comment: Interesting after the reboot I can now ping the instance. I couldn't before but I still can't telnet. I'll try adding back an allow port 80 http rule. (I understood no rules is anything goes but worth a try)  ... oh didn't work ... can't connect to port 80 via telnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is only listening on localhost:

> tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8080       :::*                        LISTEN

It needs to be listening on 0.0.0.0 which, according to the [docs](https://grizzly.java.net/httpserverframework.html) requires a different constructor.

Comment: Is that a grizzy thing or an AWS thing ? (developer away right at the moment) I still can't telnet to port 80 on the machine.

Comment: It is a grizzly thing - the constructor needs to listen on any address, not localhost (127.0.0.1).